# automation error with adding filter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add an AutoFilter to a sheet in an excel file:

```
'---- SLIDE THREE ----
Sub SlideTangerine3() 'reportWeek As String)

'Declare variables
Dim pre As Presentation
Dim slide As slide
Dim textbox As Shape
Dim book As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim switch As String

'Set variables
Set pre = ActivePresentation
Set slide = pre.Slides(3)

'-----------------------------------------------------

Set book = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set sheet = book.Worksheets(3)

If Not sheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    sheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If

book.Close

End Sub
```

I click run, vba editor freezes

After ending process, I get message "automation error the remote procedure call failed"

Comment: I don't see any arguments specified for your filter. Have you [read this?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott I just want the filters to be there, that's it

Comment: arguments are all optional and that should not make a difference. Possibly something with the workbook, check whether it opens in protected or editing mode, etc.?

Comment: First Q for you: If you run this code on another workbook  (Set book = Workbooks.Add` for example), does it work, or do you still get an error?

Comment: @DavidZemens I just created a new xlsx file. It gets the same freeze/error.

Comment: Is this the *only* bit of code you are trying to run?  And I don't understand what happens, does it "freeze" **or** do you get an error message? AFAIK, both conditions cannot occur. Either it freezes (and you have to Ctrl+Alt+Delete or kill process from Task Manager), **or** you get an error message. If an error message, what line does the error occur?

Comment: @DavidZemens yes this is the only bit of code. First it freezes, so I end the process in the taskbar, then the error pops up.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: close Excel (if ncessary, kill any orphaned Excel instances from Task manager) and try to execute these 5 lines of code from a *new* workbook. You are not doing any intra-application (e.g., between Excel/Word, or Excel/PPT, etc.) manipulation, right?  This is [a documented issue with Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618) under some circumstances.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm running from a ppt vba script, actually, so yes it is technically an intra-application procedure.

Comment: So there is more than just these 5 lines of code? Please post the rest of it.

Comment: @DavidZemens I added the rest of the code but none of them are very significant. When I remove the .AutoFilter line and add something else the script runs fine.

Comment: I would expect this error if there is some dialog waiting for user input.  See if that is happening: after `Set book = ...` do `book.Application.Visible = True` and put a breakpoint on the next line. Then look at Excel and see if there is any open dialog?

Comment: Also, you are doing `book.close` without `book.save`. If you have been working with multiple files (perhaps from other procedures/etc.) and are closing without saving, a dialog will be open asking whether you want to save changes.

Comment: @DavidZemens no dialog box

Comment: @DavidZemens adding that lined fixed the problem, thank you very much

Comment: which line solved it? Book.save?

Comment: @DavidZemens book.Application.Visible = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments above, I do notice that you're doing `book.close` without `book.save`.  This will raise a dialog asking you to save or discard changes to the workbook. Applying the AutoFilter -- even without any conditions -- is a "change".

Because Excel Application is not visible, you don't see this dialog, and it is stuck in an infinite waiting for you to respond (but you can't respond, because you can't see it!).  Either of these methods I think should resolve your problem.

**Option 1** Make the workbook visible. This will allow the dialog to display, and then you can choose to save or discard changes.

```
Sub SlideTangerine3() 'reportWeek As String)

'Declare variables
Dim pre As Presentation
Dim slide As slide
Dim textbox As Shape
Dim book As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim switch As String

'Set variables
Set pre = ActivePresentation
Set slide = pre.Slides(3)

'-----------------------------------------------------

Set book = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
book.Application.Visible = True
Set sheet = book.Worksheets(3)

If Not sheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    sheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If

book.Close

End Sub
```

**Option 2** explicitly save (or don't save) the file, this will avoid the dialog box altogether:

```
Sub SlideTangerine3() 'reportWeek As String)

'Declare variables
Dim pre As Presentation
Dim slide As slide
Dim textbox As Shape
Dim book As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim switch As String

'Set variables
Set pre = ActivePresentation
Set slide = pre.Slides(3)

'-----------------------------------------------------

Set book = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set sheet = book.Worksheets(3)

If Not sheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    sheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If

book.Close True 
'### OR to discard changes, use this:
'book.Close False

End Sub
```